# (TCP) Server responds FIN,ACK before getting ACK from Client

Tags: tcp

I've read some similar questions but I think this one has not been done yet. The thing is, once the Server gets the petition to provide a file to the Client, this one sends the info with [ACK] and [PSH,ACK] and does not wait to get a response from Client acknowledging that it has recieved the file properly to send [FIN,ACK]. I don't know if it's supposed to do that but I don't think so.

[WireShark analysis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR8dD.jpg)

Comment: You need to debug it at the server end, check its logs etc. We have no idea what is supposed to be running.

Answer (score 0):

The FIN from the server just says that the server is done sending data. The server can still read data from the client. While not very common this behavior is allowed within the TCP standard. It can for example be achieved by calling `shutdown(fd, SHUT_WR)` on the server side.

Comment: Thanks! I guess that explains the whole situation